# Elastic BeanStalk MultiContainer docker fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to deploy an multi-container application in elastic beanstalk. I get the following error.

> Error 1: The EC2 instances failed to communicate with AWS Elastic
>   Beanstalk, either because of configuration problems with the VPC or a
>   failed EC2 instance. Check your VPC configuration and try launching
>   the environment again.

I have set up the VPC with just the public subnet and the security group that allows all traffic both inbound and outbound. I know this is not encouraged for production level deployment, but I have reduced the complexity to find the cause of the error.

So, the load balancer and the EC2 instance are inside the same public subnet that is attached with the internet gateway. They both share the same security group allowing all the traffic.

Before the above error, I also get another error stating

> **Error 2: No ecs task definition (or empty definition file) found in environment**

Having said, I have bundled my **`Dockerrun.aws.json` file with `.ebextensions` folder** inside the source bundle which the beanstalk uses for deployment.
After all these errors, drilling down to two questions:

1. I cannot understand why **No ecs task error** appears, when I have packaged my `dockerrun.aws.json` file containing containerDefinitions?
2. Since there is no ecs task running, there is nothing running in the instance. Is this why beanstalk and ELB cannot communicate to the instance? (Assuming my public subnet and all traffic security group is not a problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the VPC. Even I had the simple VPC with just an public subnet, the beanstalk cannot talk to the instance and so cannot deploy the ECS task definition and docker containers in the instance.

By creating two subnets namely public and private and having an NAT instance in public subnet, which becomes the router for the instances in the private subnet. Making the above setup worked for me and I could deploy the ECS task definition successfully to the EC2 instance in the private subnet.

Answer (score 4):

I found this question because I got the same error. Here are the steps that worked for me to actually deploy a multi-container app on Beanstalk:

To get past *this particular* error, I used the `eb` CLI tools. For some reason, using `eb deploy` instead of zipping and uploading myself fixed this. It didn't actually work, but it gave me a new error.

So, I changed my `Dockerrun.aws.json`, a file format that needs WAY more documentation, until I stopped getting errors about **that**.

Then, I got an even better error!

```
ERROR: [Instance: i-0*********0bb37cf] Command failed on instance. 
Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)..._api_call
raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when 
calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
Failed to download authentication credentials [config file name] from [bucket name].
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/02update-
credentials.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log 
using console or EB CLI.
```

Per [this part of the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html#iam-instanceprofile-addperms) the way to solve this is to

1. Open the [Roles](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#roles) page in the IAM console.
2. Choose aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role.
3. On the Permissions tab, under Managed Policies, choose Attach Policy.
4. Select the managed policy for the additional services that your application uses. For example, `AmazonS3FullAccess` or `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess`. (For our problem, the S3 one)
5. Choose Attach Policies.

This part got really exciting, because I got yet another error: `Authentication credentials are not in JSON format as expected. Please generate the credentials using 'docker login'.` (Keep in mind, I tried to follow [the instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-images-private) on how to do this to the letter, but, oh well). Turns out this one was on me, I had malformed JSON in my DockerHub auth file stored on S3. I renamed the file to `dockercfg.json` to get syntax checking, and it seems the Beanstalk/ECS is okay with having the `.json` as part of the name, because this time... there was a different error: `CannotPullContainerError: Error: image [DockerHub organization]/[repo name]:latest not found)`. Hmm, maybe there was a typo? Let's check:

```
$ docker run -it [DockerHub organization]/[repo name]:latest
Unable to find image '[DockerHub organization]/[repo name]:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from [DockerHub organization]/[repo name]
```

Ok, the repo is there. So... my auth is bad? Yup, turns out I followed an example in the DockerHub auth docs that was of what you *shouldn't* do. Your `dockercfg.json` should look like

```
{
  "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
    "auth": "ZWpMQ=Vyd5zOmFsluMTkycN0ZGYmbn=WV2FtaGF2",
    "email": "your@email.com"
  }
}
```

There were a few more errors (volume `sourcePath` has to be a absolute path! That's what the `invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed` message means), but it eventually deployed. Sorry for the novel; hoping it helps someone.

Comment: https://github.com/micahhausler/container-transform was really helpful with Dockerrun.aws.json format

Comment: Hey, great answer / tutorial! There is only one question left: how do you exactly specify the dockercfg.json in your Dockerrun.aws.json? The bucketname is clear, but the "key"...is it the filename??

Comment: My section in Dockerrun.aws.json looks: `{
 "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
 "authentication": {
     "bucket": "elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-xxxxxxx464",
     "key": "config.json"
   },
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {...` and I have granted `AmazonS3FullAccess`. Still I get `CannotPullContainerError: API error (500): Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/XYZ/db/manifests/latest: denied: access forbidden php: `

Comment: `"authentication": {
        "bucket": "my-bucket",
        "key": "mydockercfg"
      },`

Comment: thx, I solved my problem. The format for the credential file config.json is just `{
  "registry.gitlab.com": {
   "auth": "xxxx"
  }
}`. I had to switch off the usage of my Mac's credential manager and delete my local config.json. Then, after performing docker login locally, the file was recreated with this new access token (I think it's OAuth ?).